# Foreach loop in Reviews.io API for Products

Tags: php, json, api

I'm very new to the world of APIs and am currently trying to display all reviews I have on my reviews.io account for a specific product. I've tried to make the following script, which now seems to work, however, I would love to have the results sorted nicely in a for-each loop.

**Here my current script:**

```
    <?php
        $header_data = array(
            'store' => 'MYSHOP',
            'apikey' => 'MYKEY',
            'method'  => 'GET'
             );

        $ch = curl_init();
        $curlOpts = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.reviews.co.uk/product/review?store=MYSHOP&sku=TSCB20&apikey=MYKEY',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false
        );  
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOpts);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: 0'));   
        $rv = curl_exec($ch);
        $data = json_decode($rv,true);

        curl_close($ch);

    ?>
```

This outputs all reviews in Raw code or JSON I believe, however, I would like to have them displayed nicely in a div for each item.

**The output is as follows (formatted):**

```
    {
      "store": {
        "name": "",
        "logo": ""
      },
      "stats": {
        "average": "5.0000",
        "count": 2
      },
      "reviews": {
        "total": 2,
        "per_page": 15,
        "current_page": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "to": 2,
        "data": [
          {
            "votes": null,
            "flags": null,
            "title": "David",
            "product_review_id": 2978412,
            "review": "...is beautiful and I had a great time on this tour. Already started to plan my next trip with them",
            "sku": "TSCB20",
            "rating": 5,
            "date_created": "",
            "order_id": "",
            "timeago": "",
            "reviewer": {
              "first_name": "David",
              "last_name": "",
              "verified_buyer": "yes",
              "address": "",
              "profile_picture": "",
              "gravatar": "38677a4e8a55189055d6e5bf2efa9ade"
            },
            "ratings": [],
            "replies": [],
            "images": [],
            "product": {
              "sku": "TSCB20",
              "name": "",
              "description": "",
              "link": "",
              "image_url": "",
              "mpn": "",
              "brand": null,
              "category": null,
              "custom": null
            },
            "author": {
              "email": "david@"
            }
          },
          {
            "votes": null,
            "flags": null,
            "title": null,
            "product_review_id": 2978009,
            "review": "Exceeded expectations on all fronts cultural and Food ",
            "sku": "TSCB20",
            "rating": 5,
            "date_created": "",
            "order_id": "RGFY4ZG",
            "timeago": "",
            "reviewer": {
              "first_name": "Alan",
              "last_name": "",
              "verified_buyer": "yes",
              "address": "",
              "profile_picture": "",
              "gravatar": "64e2ac644a158b76a82f9e1c5c2886f5"
            },
            "ratings": [],
            "replies": [],
            "images": [],
            "product": {
              "sku": "TSCB20",
              "name": "",
              "description": "",
              "link": "",
              "image_url": "",
              "mpn": "",
              "brand": null,
              "category": null,
              "custom": null
            },
            "author": {
              "email": ""
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "ratings": [],
      "settings": {
        "write_review_button": 1,
        "disable_product_seo_css": 0,
        "show_product_review_titles": 0
      },
      "word": "Excellent",
      "products": [
        {
          "sku": "TSCB20",
          "name": ""
        }
      ],
      "write_review_link": ""
    }
```

My ideal outcome now would be a loop, that fetches the reviewer's name, the review itself and the star-rating. e.g.

```
    <p class="review">Review here</p>
    <p class="reviewer">Name here</p>
    <p class="rating">Rating here</p>
```

So technically based on the current output, I should have 2 reviews. Some expert help would be greatly appreciated as I am very new to APIs. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `foreach()` will do the job:

```
<?php foreach($data['reviews']['data'] as $dat){?>

    <p class="review"><?php echo $dat['review'];?></p>

    <p class="reviewer"><?php echo trim($dat['reviewer']['first_name'].' '.$dat['reviewer']['last_name']);?></p>

    <p class="rating"><?php echo $dat['rating'];?></p>
<?php }?>
```